# Adding certificate in keystore

Tags: cmd, webclient, keystore

I am adding my certificate in keystore through this command:

```
keytool -import -alias joe -keystore my.keystore -file my_recently_exported.cer
```

After I run this command on cmd is says that certificate was added to keystore.
However when I run command:

```
keytool -list
```

it says that keystore file does not exist. I don't know what should I do now. Any suggessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keytool will look for a keystone file named '.keystore' by default, so you should use

```
keytool -list -keystore my.keystore
```

Hope this helps,